# Как получить id беседы в которой написано сообщение

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api

Я постоянно при любых командах использовал message.chat, но в функции это не работает как реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(message){ ... }, 3000, message);
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/L749pTg

Comment: откуда берется объект `message`?

Comment: Честно говоря не сильно знаю, но как я понял, то mesage.send да и сам message берется из модуля vk-io т.к у меня бот для вк.

Comment: Покажите хоть немного кода вокруг Вашего вызова `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `message.chat` используй `message.chatId` с соблюдением регистра. (`i` должна быть большой)